# How do I test a view controller after subscription to an Observable is done?

Tags: macos, cocoa, rx-swift

In the below example, how do I wait until the success callback is called to start asserting in my view controller tests?

```
class VC : NSViewController {
    let observable: Observable<Int>
    let compositeDisposable = CompositeDisposable()
    override viewDidLoad() {
        self.compositeDisposable.insert(
            self.observable.toArray()
            .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(
                // draw onto the VC
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything here that can be tested. What is it you would assert on in the first place?

Comment: @DanielT. i would like to test `vc.view` to see the proper subviews have been added.